# Angular 2 Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular2, angular-routing

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { MainTableService } from './main.table-service';
import { Corps } from './corps';



@Component ({
    selector: 'main-table',
    templateUrl: 'app/main-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/main-table.component.css']
})

export class MainTableComponent implements OnInit {
    errorMessage: string;
    corpsData: Corps[];


    constructor(
        private mainTableService: MainTableService,
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getCorpsData();
    }

    getCorpsData() {
        this.mainTableService.getCorpsData()
            .subscribe(
                corpsData => this.corpsData = corpsData,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }



    onSelect(corp: Corps): void {
        this.router.navigate(['/details', corp.ID]);

    }

}
```

Доброго времени суток. Работаю с небольшим приложением на Angular2 и после переноса его на сервер возникла проблема с роутингом. Ранее все лежало в корне на рабочем компьютере и работало вполне правильно. Теперь же приложение лежит на удаленном сервере в папке /static/dat. Ожидаемо поломались все пути, но это починить удалось, а вот с роутингом никак не выходит. 
Так что в очередной раз вернул все на исходную и вот что есть -

```html
<head>
    <base href="/">
```

это в index.html

тут идет настройка роутера

```js
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { MainTableComponent } from "./main-table.component";
import { MainTableService } from "./main.table-service";
import { SelectedDetailsComponent } from "./selected-details.component";
import { SearchService } from "./search-service";
import {SelectedDetailsService} from "./selected.details-service";

@NgModule({
    imports:      [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: 'details/:ID',
                component: SelectedDetailsComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'corporations',
                component: MainTableComponent
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/corporations',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MainTableComponent,
        SelectedDetailsComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        MainTableService,
        SearchService,
        SelectedDetailsService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
```

ну и на выходе получаем страницу без подгруженых темплейтов и кучу ошибок вида EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'static/dat'

Я уже игрался с путями как мог и дописывал и менял, но пока на выходе все то же самое. Добавил пример компонента

Comment: вообще в большинстве случаев помогло бы изменение `<base href="/">` На то, где сейчас находится index.html, Ну или какой там файлик запускается по умолчанию

Comment: я все перекинул и поменял ссылку. вернул конфиги к прежнему состоянию. index.html находится в static/dat/index.html.
однако, стоило мне поменять эту штуку на  <base href="static/dat/"> как путь ко всему начал считаться как - 
GET http://IP/static/dat/static/dat/styles.css 
внезапные запросы, да.

Comment: какая система сборки используется?

Comment: впервые делаю так что все руками. Редактирую пока на сервере и перезаливаю.

Comment: так что в итоге пока <base href="/static/dat/">

и ошибки GET http://IP/static/dat/static/dat/app/selected-details.component.html

Пока не могу понять, почему оно путь вставляет 2 раза в запрос

Comment: добавь пример компонента

Comment: Добавил main-table.component.ts

Comment: _templateUrl: 'app/main-table.component.html',_ - попробуй `/` добавить в начале

Comment: к сожалению, осталось все так же.

Comment: то есть, вот с таким путем _/app/main-table.component.html_ все еще дублируется адрес? Попробуй сделать [mcve] на [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue), или подобном сервисе

Comment: пока выдает вот это 
 GET http://IP/static/dat/static/dat/app/selected-details.component.html 404 (Not Found)
 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load static/dat/app/selected-details.component.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load static/dat/app/selected-details.component.html undefined

сейчас гляну что можно сделать с примером. На рабочем компе все работало в том виде, в котором было, а тут чтот никак пока.

Comment: на рабочему работало как раз из-за того что все в корне было. Странно что дублирование осталось

Comment: пока вот это есть. покидал немного подредактированные js прямо с сервера. оно ужасно, но если есть желание, то хоть общий вид посмотреть можно.  https://plnkr.co/edit/jVVM4o3CnAqEjPHhtTp1?p=preview

Comment: ага, то есть system.js все-таки используется. Он вроде и тайпскриптовые файлы понимает - для полноты картины

Comment: да. и там я конфигурацию не менял. и дублирования пути тоже не было - один настырный человек весь проект просмотрел.

Comment: я понял. тут angular-in-memory-web-api' забыл убрать. видимо, оно и дублировало. по крайней мере, контент загрузился

Comment: Я бы добавил трейс и заодно useHash в router, примерно так:
`RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { enableTracing: true, useHash: true })`
и поглядел что там творится при переходе.

ЗЫ. и поглядел бы в сторону angular-cli, а то захочется потом упаковку кода или AOT вместо JIT и руками задолбаешься это все делать.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. решил проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло добавление в индекс  пути, где сейчас index.html + я забыл убрать из конфига angular-in-memory-web-api.